# Zero-copy receive and message size

Tags: zeromq

Is there a way to query the size of the received message, when using zero-copy for receiving?

With this I (try to) achieve zero-copy:

```
zmq_recv(sock, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
```

I also tried:

```
zmq_msg_t msg;
zmq_msg_init_data (&msg, buf, sizeof(buf), nullptr, NULL);
zmq_msg_recv(&msg, sock, 0);
size_t len = zmq_msg_size(&msg);
```

This returns correct size, but does not fill `buf`. I think `zmq_msg_init_data` is not intended for use with `zmq_msg_recv` and the message rebuilds on receive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the [guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Zero-Copy) on zero-copy:

> There is no way to do zero-copy on receive: ZeroMQ delivers you a buffer that you can store as long as you wish, but it will not write data directly into application buffers.

Zero-copy is for sending only, not for receiving.

Oh and `zmq_recv` *returns* the number of bytes received.

Comment: When googling 'zmq_recv' I was redirected to zmq 2.1 documentation and overlooked that this is very old.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the JeroMQ (Pure Java for ZeroMQ), you may achieve the zero-copy on the receive side by ZMQ.Socket.setMsgAllocator

Generaly speaking, we just care the zero copy for large object, so you can set a custom message allocator
for example:

```
class MappedMemoryMsgAllocator implements MsgAllocator {

static final MsgAllocatorHeap heap = new MsgAllocatorHeap();
private final int threshold;

public MappedMemoryMsgAllocator(int threshold) {
    this.threshold = threshold;
}

public MappedMemoryMsgAllocator() {
    this(1024 * 1024 * 4);
}

@Override
public Msg allocate(int size) {
    if ((threshold > 0) && (size > threshold)) {
        try {
            return new Msg(UtilsJNI.nativeMapMemory(size, UtilsJNI.PROT_WRITE, UtilsJNI.MAP_PRIVATE));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "allocate:: fail to mmap", e);
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        return heap.allocate(size);
    }
}

public static void forceFreeMsgArray(zmq.Msg[] msgs) {
    if (msgs != null) {
        for (zmq.Msg msg : msgs) {
            final ByteBuffer buf = msg.buf();
            if (buf.isDirect()) {
                try {
                    UtilsJNI.nativeUnmapMemory(buf);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

native C++ code:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jobject
UtilsJNI_nativeMapMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jlong size,
                                              jint protection, jint mapFlags) {
    void *pAddr = mmap64(NULL, size, protection, mapFlags|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (pAddr == NULL) {
        env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass("java/io/IOException"), "fail to mmap");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return env->NewDirectByteBuffer(pAddr, size);
    }
}

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void
UtilsJNI_nativeUnmapMemory(JNIEnv *env, jobject clazz, jobject buffer) {
    if (munmap(env->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer), env->GetDirectBufferCapacity(buffer)) < 0) {
        env->ThrowNew(env->FindClass("java/io/IOException"), "fail to munmap");
    }
}
```